# Assembly in C - Printing specific word backwards

Tags: c, assembly

I have a huge problem with printing the specific word backwards. I'm trying to find words with '*' at the beggining and print them backwards, the rest should be printed normally.

***For example:***

**Input**: `aaa1     ab0  1kk   *ddd *lel 2cccc2   c1`

**Output** `aaa1 ab0 1kk ddd* lel* 2cccc2 c1`

All I have is finding the words, finding the ones with '*' and printing normally the words without '*'.
Please help me and thank you in advance for your attention to this matter...

Have to write it in C language and here's my code

```
int main() {
    char *x = "aaa1 ab0  1kk *ddd  *lel 

2cccc2 c1";
    char bufor[100];
    asm volatile (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "mov eax, %0;"
        "push eax;"
        "mov eax, %1;"
        "push eax;"
        "call zadanie1;"
        "jmp wyjscie;"
        "zadanie1:"
        //
        //  FUNCTION START
        //
        "pushad;"                           
        "mov esi, [esp+40];"                
        "mov edx, [esp+36];"               
        "push edx;"
        "xor ecx, ecx;"
        // MAIN LOOP - WORDS SEARCHING
        "zad_loop:"
        "mov edx, [esp];"
        "lodsb;"                            
        "test al, al;"
        "jz zad_loop_end;"                 
        "cmp al, 0x20;"
        "jz zad_loop_end;"                 
        "mov [edx+ecx], al;"               
        "inc ecx;"                          
        "jmp zad_loop;"   
        // MAIN LOOP END
        "zad_loop_end:"
        "mov [edx+ecx], ch;"                
        "push eax;"
        "push ecx;"

        "test ecx, ecx;"
        "jz not_print;"
        // IS THE FIRST CHAR '*'
        "lea eax, [edx];"
        "mov al, [eax];"
        "cmp al, '*';"
        "jz backwards;"

        "test al, al;"
        "jz not_print;"
        // PRINTING THE WORD WITHOUT '*'
        "mov edx, [esp];"                   
        "mov ecx, [esp+8];"                 
        "mov ebx, 1;"
        "push eax;"                        
        "mov eax, 4;"
        "int 0x80;"
        "push 0x20;"                       
        "call print_char;"
        "pop eax;"                         

        // PRINTING THE WORD WITH '*' - BACKWARDS
        "backwards:"


        // SKIP PRINTING
        "not_print:"
        "pop ecx;"
        "pop eax;"
        "xor ecx, ecx;"
        "test al, al;"                      
        "jnz zad_loop;"                    

        // FUNCTION END
        "pop edx;"
        "push 0x0A;"                         


        "call print_char;"
        "popad;"                            
        "ret 8;"                          

        // CHAR OUTPUT
        "print_char:"
        "pushad;"
        "mov edx, 1;"
        "lea ecx, [esp+36];"
        "mov ebx, 1;"
        "mov eax, 4;"
        "int 0x80;"
        "popad;"
        "ret 4;"


        "wyjscie:"
        ".att_syntax prefix;"
        :
        : "r" (x), "r" (bufor)
        : "eax"
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've posted a load of assembler then said you have to write your solution in C. What exactly do you want from us?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know how to print the letters of a word, one letter at a time, going forward.  And you know how to find the end of a word.  But you don't know how to find the end of a word and print the letters one letter at a time going backword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designate a register to be a counter (pick any one you aren't using for other stuff) and set its value to 0.

When you hit a * character, push characters onto the stack until it finds a blank, incrementing the counter with each push.

When a blank is found, pop characters off the stack, decrementing the counter and printing the character each time, until the counter is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your compiler, but I think your compiler would insert the code that you wrote as text in variables instead of compiling the instructions, because a text that begins with  a  "  will be interpreted as text. Drop these chars.